# Properly type-guarding custom RxJS pipeable operators

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-typings, rxjs-pipeable-operators, custom-operator

I am working with an API that has a fixed, consistent structure of responses: it is always an object that has a `data` property on it. As it is very tiresome and too explicit to constantly map the data in RxJS requests (or ngrx effects), I decided to introduce a custom RxJS operator that plucks the data and applies an optional callback.

But now some of my effects complain about the type information (like: `property x doesn't exist on type {}`), so I guess my effort to properly type-guard the operator's I/O isn't enough:

```
export function mapData<T, R>(callback?: (T) => R) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(
    map(value => value['data'] as R), // isn't that an equivalent of `pluck<T>('data')` ?
    map(value => typeof callback === 'function' ? callback(value) : value as R),
  );
}
```

An example of ngrx effect with type-guard problems :

```
switchMap(() => this.api.getData().pipe(
  mapData(),
  mergeMap(data => [
     new actions.DataSuccessAction({ id: data.id }), // <-- id does not exist on type {}
     new actions.SomeOtherAction(data),
  ]),
  catchError(err => of(new actions.DataFailureAction(err))),
)),
```

Which of course goes away when I type-cast it explicitly:

```
mapData<any, IMyData>(....),
```

I would love to hear whether this is the right, TypeScript way to do stuff.

Comment: `T` is the source type and that can be inferred from the `pipe` call. but where would `R` be inferred from ?

Comment: If a callback is passed, then it could be inferred - most often it would be of type of an action. When theere is no callback, I have to typecast it explicitly.

Comment: You access `data` on `T` does this mean `T` must have a `data` property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple overloads to model different type behaviors. I am not 100% sure what the behavior should be, it's not 100% clear from your question, but my reading of it suggests the following rules:

1. If `T` has `data` and no `callback` is specified return `data`
2. If we specify `callback` then the return is dictated by `callback`
3. If no `callback` is specified and 1 does not apply just return `T`

An overloaded version would look something like this:

```
export function mapData<T, R>(callback: (data: T) => R) : OperatorFunction<T, R>
export function mapData<T extends { data: any }>() : OperatorFunction<T, T['data']>
export function mapData<T>() : OperatorFunction<T, T>
export function mapData<T extends { data? : undefined } | { data: R }, R>(callback?: (data: T) => R) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(
    map(value => typeof callback === 'function' ? callback(value) : (value.data ? value.data : value)),
  );
}

// Tests
of({ data: { id: 0 }}).pipe(
  mapData(),
  mergeMap(data => [
    new actions.DataSuccessAction({ id: data.id }), // <-- id does not exist on type {}
    new actions.SomeOtherAction(data),
  ]),
  catchError(err => of(new actions.DataFailureAction(err))),
)

of({ other: { id: 0 }}).pipe(
  mapData(d =>d.other),
  mergeMap(data => [
    new actions.DataSuccessAction({ id: data.id }), // <-- id does not exist on type {}
    new actions.SomeOtherAction(data),
  ]),
  catchError(err => of(new actions.DataFailureAction(err))),
)

of({ data: { id: 0 }}).pipe(
  mapData(d =>d.data),
  mergeMap(data => [
    new actions.DataSuccessAction({ id: data.id }), // <-- id does not exist on type {}
    new actions.SomeOtherAction(data),
  ]),
  catchError(err => of(new actions.DataFailureAction(err))),
)



// Filler classes
namespace actions {
  export class DataSuccessAction<T>{
    constructor(public data:T){}
  }
  export class SomeOtherAction<T>{
    constructor(public data:T){}
  }

  export class DataFailureAction<T>{
    constructor(public data:T){}
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I wouldn't even think I need 4 signatures for 2 cases ;-) Your answer is very helpful and instructive! Based on it, I hope I will be able to make yet another custom operator `mapError` :)

Comment: @user776686 the last signature is not publicly visible so it does not count :) Let me know if you need any help with `mapError` always looking for fun type problems ;)

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that!